# Is it feasible to scale coordinates in onDraw() in a custom view?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-view

I am developing a 2D android game, and I have implemented a custom view to do so. Right now, I am using almost 50 ratios to determine where to position various game elements like:

```
int posX = screenWidth / 3;
```

However, I think it would be easier to use a fixed number of units, and scale accordingly like so:

```
public class ScaleCanvas {
    private static final int WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 100;

    private int mUnitPixels;

    ScaleCanvas(int pWidth) {
        mUnitPixels = pWidth / WIDTH;
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap, int pX, int pY, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, pX * mUnitPixels, pY * mUnitPixels, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(src.left * mUnitPixels, src.top * mUnitPixels, src.right * mUnitPixels,
                src.bottom * mUnitPixels), new Rect(dst.left * mUnitPixels, dst.top * mUnitPixels, dst.right
                * mUnitPixels, dst.bottom * mUnitPixels), paint);
    }
}
```

For a game running at 50 FPS, would it decrease performance severely to call several drawBitmap() functions from this class for every frame? If so, what are the alternatives?

Comment: If you are worried about performance, you should be using OpenGL ES or LibGDX instead of a custom view.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I believe that OpenGL ES is unsuitable for 2D games. I have not heard of LibGDX before.

Comment: "I believe that OpenGL ES is unsuitable for 2D games." Not at all. Many 2D games are implemented with OpenGL ES or LibGDX, much of which is a wrapper around OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about performance, I suggest that you use OpenGL ES or LibGDX instead of a custom view.